# optaplanner: dynamic domain model

Tags: optaplanner

I have a question about OptaPlanner. In the examples are an example called PatientAdmissionSchedule and it's based on an domain model. It's possible to build the domain model a little bit more dynamic with generics? I would like to figure the domain model but it's must be for some use case different in some relations and entities.

Has optaplanner for dynamic domain models an own schema which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **optaplanner workbench** you can design a model at runtime in the webUI and deploy it as a jar to **optaplanner execution server**.

If you want to programmatically control the reflection, we don't officially support that yet: create an issue and hack `SolutionDescriptor`, `EntityDescriptor` and `VariableDescriptor`.

Comment: Hi, I am also interested in a programmatically interface. In your answer you have written it is not available yet. I am wondering if you had a chance to follow this road further? Do you have feature requests for this?

Comment: I don't think we have a jira yet. Feel free to create a jira and link it here, so we can track demand. Do note that this issue isn't a priority (not enough community demand nor a customer escalation), so the fastest way to get it done it do submit a Pull Request to resolves it...